# В контексте: "не/модный" — раздельно или слитно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, прилагательные

> К сожалению, в настоящее время театр приходит в упадок. Дело не только
>   в том, что у него нет денег. Ходить в театр стало «немодным».

Это я его сделала слитным, не вынесла душа поэта.

Comment: А кавычки тоже Ваши? Я бы убрал.

Comment: Не, кавычки интервьюируемой. Того, кто за ней записывает. Но спасибо - я передам!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этом контексте я бы написала слитно. "Немодный" здесь противоположно по значению прилагательным  *популярный, престижный*.
[**Новый объяснительный словарь синонимов русского языка**](https://synonims_pic.academic.ru/765/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

*В последние три года у вас **стало немодным** хорошо учиться.*
[**А. Маринина. Чужая маска**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=YD8QhfDl7m4C&pg=PT168&lpg=PT168&dq=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC&source=bl&ots=3MCDb6PW26&sig=P9JlwPeZaPGgeG81BoVta380fK8&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgwPXasK3YAhVJKpoKHfQ6AmMQ6AEIUzAH#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC&f=false)

*Смысл в том, что с некоторых пор **стало немодным** кремировать усопших.*
С. Стоян. Закон сохранения

*Сочинительство **стало немодным**.*
И. Ефремов. Лезвие бритвы